# Install Ubuntu 16.04.1, removing Fedora 22

Tags: system-installation, fedora

I'm trying to install Ubuntu and remove Fedora. I approached problem. I choose to erase disk and install Ubuntu then I choose disk that is showed in picture but as I press "Install Now" nothing happens. And if I press "Install Now" button again I'm ending up again in last step where I should choose to erase disk and etc. What should I do? Please help.

Choose type:
[image]

Choose disk:
[image]

Comment: Sorry for bad quality of pictures;x

Comment: Consider using "something else", remove all the partitions and recreate as you wish for Ubuntu. Only / and swap are need but other partitioning schemes can be used.